# How to inject pictures from the phones gallery into the camera feed in real time?

Tags: applications, root-access, samsung, camera, android-emulator

An android app is requesting pictures from the camera feed. I wish to inject the picture from my gallery rather than doing it in real-time. Any tools on rooted phones or android emulators for this? Thanks!

Comment: If the app starts the default camera app to do so,there might be an app that could do this. But if it tries to access the camera directly, a rooted phone will not be enough and you'll need an app for Xposed to do it. Even that wouldn't work if your app uses native APIs.